# Exception reading *.htm file from local app data (Metro App)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm using `FileIO.ReadTextAsync()` to read an *.htm webpage which I have saved into "ms-appdata:///local", using Utf8 encoding.

But I get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when doing it. Additional information is `No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page`.

Reading an ordinary *.txt file using the same function works fine. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit : Code

```
async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
StorageFile SF = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/test3.html"));
string html = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(SF, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
}
```

Comment: You should add the code (or shortest possible example) to produce this issue

Comment: You're right - done now

Comment: Is the htm file actually in UTF-8? The error suggests that it's not. Can you share a file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT That's probably it; I realized that even if I got it to work correctly it wouldn't solve my purpose so now I'm using code from another metro project [link](http://offline.codeplex.com) to load html pages into `WebView` from the local file system outside of the app package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the file encoding using Visual Studio. When I opened the file it had the encoding: "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252"

1. Open the file in Visual Studio
2. File > Advanced Save Options... >
3. Change the encoding to "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"[image: Advanced save options]
4. Save the file

Credits: [Advanced save options in visual studio](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/09/winrt-argumentoutofrangeexception-no.html)